# Display updated tree table value from another tree table

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable

I am trying to make a scene editor to go with my rendering engine. I am using swing to make the GUI and also swingx for its `JXTreeTable` component. Everything is working fine, except that the Scene tree table is not updating the names of the nodes automatically as I would like. For example, in the next image, I change the name of one of the nodes, and nothing seems to happen. However if I then move my mouse over the node in the Scene box (the one at the top) the name gets updated.

[image]

I have two `JXTreeTable`, and two models which extend `AbstractTreeTableModel`.
Here is the relevant code for the Properties model.

```
public class PropertiesModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel{
    private EE_Property root;
    private SceneModel mSceneModel;
    private EE_SceneObject sceneSelection;

    ...

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, Object node, int column){
        ((EE_Property)node).setValue((String)value);

        // Updates the values of the current scene selection
        sceneSelection.setProperties(root);

        TreePath path = new TreePath(sceneSelection.getParent());
        int index = mSceneModel.getIndexOfChild(sceneSelection.getParent(), sceneSelection);

        // This is where I thought the updating of the scene model would happen and thus redraw it correctly
        mSceneModel.getTreeModelSupport().fireChildChanged(path, index, sceneSelection);
    }
}
```

I thought that using `fireChildChanged()` would update the scene tree table as I wanted.

If I call `fireChildChanged()` with index=0, I can get the Root node to update when I rename it, but any other index I have to wait till I move the mouse over it to update.

**Edit: problem solved**

I tried the redraw method suggested by @Shakedown which partially worked but sometimes would leave "..." after the text if the new text was longer than the original.

I did however realize that the problem was coming from the TreePath not being generated properly. When using `TreePath path = new TreePath(sceneSelection.getParent());`, the path's parent was null, thus not allowing the tree to update. I now use this code which works :

```
// mTT is the scene tree table
TreePath nodePath = mSceneModel.mTT.getTreeSelectionModel().getSelectionPath(); 
int index = mSceneModel.getIndexOfChild(sceneSelection.getParent(), sceneSelection);
mSceneModel.getTreeModelSupport().fireChildChanged(nodePath.getParentPath(), index, sceneSelection);
```

Comment: glad you found a solution - just beware: this smells a bit as it requires to manually fire a change from the _outside_ of the model itself. The sceneModel should do so itself on detecting a change on the properties of the contained objects

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I am doing it in the wrong way after looking into @Shakedown's comments. But it has still allowed me to get something running and now I can check that my future "correct implementation" works the way I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're notifying the listeners of the `SceneModel` which is not the tree-table that you want to update. Look for some similar `fireXXX` methods on the `AbstractTreeTableModel` class and call those, which will notify the `JXTreeTable` and it will redraw itself.

It looks like the one you want is `fireTreeNodesChanged(...)`, so play around with that and figure out what parameters you need to pass in.

Comment: I do want to update the listeners of SceneModel, since this is the table at the top of the screen... Maybe I am not understanding what you are saying, but I thought that this is exactly what I am doing. My PropertiesModel class holds a reference to my SceneModel class (mSceneModel). Since I am calling the fireChildChanged on mSceneModel, shouldn't this do what I want?

Comment: Well it depends on which model is being used by the tree-table. I'm assuming that it is in fact an instance of a `PropertiesModel`, in which case the tree-table will be adding listeners to that object, not the `SceneModel` object.

Comment: The top JXTreeTable uses the SceneModel and the bottom JXTreeTable uses the PropertiesModel. Since I change the value from within the PropertiesModel (i.e. I edit something within the bottom tree table), I need to somehow update the SceneModel so that the top tree table gets updated, which is what I thought I was doing.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You probably should still notify whoever is listening on the `PropertiesModel` after a value is changed. Have you tried calling `repaint()` on the tree-table after the value changes? I would hope you don't need to, but sometimes the tree-table implementations can be buggy. Also, instead of having the `PropertiesModel` keep a reference to the `SceneModel`, you should link the two of them together with model listeners. So you would add a listener to the `PropertiesModel` and when a tree node changes you would update the `SceneModel`.

Comment: Fixed it! See my edit for how. Thanks for all the help. I marked this answer as accepted since your help lead me to the answer, and for the suggestions in your last comment, which I will try to implement now. It was by checking what was being passed to `fireTreeNodesChanged` by `fireTreeNodeChanged` that I found the mistake.